# Finding whether there is specific text in a cell, Like not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue using the `Like` operator in VBA. If I want to see if a cell contains specific text, such as "ABC" or "CBN", `Like` doesn't work for me.

Also, sometimes the cell may have the value "ABC 1", "ABC 2", "ABC 3", or anything like that. But I just want to use the `Like` to see if the cell has just the "ABC". It says that it is true even though the cell may say "ACB" or "ABD". I want it to be specifically having ABC, nothing else. How can I fix that?

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "Positions *" Then
        clause = Range("AM3") Like "ABC*"     >>>>> clause returns as TRUE if the actual cell value says ABD or ACB, this was also a test of what the line below will return
            If Range("AM3") Like "*ABC*" Then
            
            Name = "Bananas"
            
            
            End If
            
        End If
Next
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but at a guess it's because you didn't qualify the range. All your range calls need to be preceded by `ws.`

Comment: Do you think `ws.Select` is also appropriate? @Warcupine

Comment: No, there is no need to `select` anything in VBA 99.9% of the time.

Comment: I think that was the issue. Thanks!